# How to calculate RAM disk size on OS X Mojave—500 or 512 byte block size?

Tags: macos, mojave, hdiutil

I created an APFS RAM disk on macOS X 10.14 Mojave using these commands:

```
diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://12582912) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'RAMDisk' '100%'
```

Which should create a 6 GB RAM Disk. I ended up with a "6.53 GB" Ram Disk. The question is does `hdiutil` calculate block sizes as 512 bytes or 500 bytes?

**The old way was:**

1 block = 512 bytes

 2 blocks = 1024 bytes (KB) 

1024 bytes X 1024 = 1048576 bytes (MB) 

1048576 bytes x 1024 = 1073741824 bytes (GB)

1073741824 bytes / 512 = 2097152 blocks per GB

**But maybe storage is now calculated differently:**

1 block = 500 bytes 

2 blocks = 1000 bytes (KB) 

1000 bytes X 1000 = 1000000 bytes (MB) 

1000000 bytes x 1000 = 1000000000 bytes (GB)

1000000000 bytes / 500 = 2000000 blocks per GB

EDIT: Just tested this myself and ended up with these numbers which seems to indicate that `hdiutil` does indeed use 500 byte block size for calculation. There is some overhead for EFI which reduces available size but the GUID partition was 6.1 GB.

```
$ diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://12000000) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'RAMDisk' '100%'
Started partitioning on disk15
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk15s2 as APFS with name RAMDisk
Mounting disk
Finished partitioning on disk15
/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +6.1 GB     disk15
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk15s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk16        5.9 GB     disk15s2
```

Comment: To get exactly 6GB, you need 11,718,750 blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems simple enough. You asked for 12000000 sectors. The sector size is 512 bytes. So 12000000 * 512 = 6.1 GB which is the size of `disk15`. If a block size of 500 bytes was substituted for the 512 byte sector size, then the calculation would be 12000000 * 500 = 6.0 GB. This is not what is shown.

The output from `diskutil info disk15 | grep -e Size` should be as shown below.

```
   Disk Size:                 6.1 GB (6144000000 Bytes) (exactly 12000000 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes
```